# duplicate logs in fluentd, when integrating plugin fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions

Tags: fluentd

I have a basic fluentd config that uses a plugin to detect exceptions and bundle multi-line stack-trace into a single one. The problem is that it duplicates the exception logs. I get both the bundled lines and the raw lines.

The difference between [the plugins documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions) and the below config is that it uses several match directives. Fluentd does not give any information on exactly what double match directives are interpreted. One solution would be to remove the double match directive, but then how could it be sent to elasticsearch?

I suspect that it is a misunderstanding of the match directive on my part. But I can't find documentation that helps me understand why the below config does what it does.

Here's the relevant part of the fluentd config

```
    <label @DISPATCH>
      <match kubernetes.**>
        @type detect_exceptions
        remove_tag_prefix kubernetes
        multiline_flush_interval 0.2
      </match>

      <match **>
        @type relabel
        @label @OUTPUT
      </match>
    </label>
    <label @OUTPUT>
      <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        host "elasticsearch-master"
        port 9200
        path ""
        user elastic
        password changeme
      </match>
    </label>
```

Any help / pointers is very appreciated